# MT7601UM chipset USB Wifi drivers

Tags: wireless, usb, windows, ralink

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on a Dell 755.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Portable-Mini-USB-Wireless-Router-Dongle-Internet-Adapter-WI-FI-150-Mbps-/141495612384?pt=US_USB_Wi_Fi_Adapters_Dongles&hash=item20f1cbb3e0

Trying to install the above adapter. lsusb lists it as;

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:760b Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

Any instructions I have found to get this chipset (MT7601UM) do not work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! I bought 8 of these and they work great on Win 7. Just can't get it to run on Ubuntu or Zorin.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691158/archer-t2u-stopped-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please unplug the device. Get a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Insert the device and it should be working. Let us know your success as we will have one additional step.

You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel, known in Ubuntu as linux-image, after the required reboot, re-compile:

```
cd mt7601/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked the first time. Even used the WiFi connection I had already setup to connect to my home Wifi!

Comment: Awesome. Please see my edit in a few moments. If my answer is helpful, please accept it.