# Archer T2U stopped working

Tags: wireless

I originally managed to get my tp-link archer T2U working on my machine but it seems to have decided to stop working after I installed some display drivers, unsure why. I tried to reinstall the driver but that doesn't seem to be working...

I'm new to Linux so not really to sure what I'm doing

EDIT:
output of lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0161 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
3.13.0-66-generic
```

Error when trying to run make install

```
$ sudo make install
make -C UTIL/ install_util
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL'
make -C /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux -f Makefile.6.util install
make[2]: Entering directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux'
install -d /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install -m 644 -c mt7650u_sta_util.ko /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat ‘mt7650u_sta_util.ko’: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux'
make[1]: *** [install_util] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Error when running make

```
    make
make -C UTIL/ osutil
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL'
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6.util /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-66-generic/build SUBDIRS=/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-66-generic'
  CC [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
  CC [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux_symb.o
  CC [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_rbus_pci_util.o
  CC [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.o
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c: In function ‘rausb_fill_bulk_urb’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c:425:2: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘usb_fill_bulk_urb’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  usb_fill_bulk_urb(urb, dev, pipe, transfer_buffer, buffer_length, complete_fn, context);
  ^
In file included from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:40:0,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:62,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_usb_util.c:18:
include/linux/usb.h:1523:20: note: expected ‘usb_complete_t’ but argument is of type ‘USB_COMPLETE_HANDLER’
 static inline void usb_fill_bulk_urb(struct urb *urb,
                    ^
  CC [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsUsDelay’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:179:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  ULONG i;
        ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:664:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   pClonedPkt->tail = pClonedPkt->data + pClonedPkt->len;
                    ^
In file included from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:62,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:34:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktInit’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:893:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:683:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(pRxPkt, pData, DataSize);
  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:709:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpDrvAllRFPrint’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2051:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘file_w->f_op->write’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    file_w->f_op->write(file_w, pBuf, BufLen, &file_w->f_pos);
    ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2051:4: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘UINT32 *’
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2036:22: warning: unused variable ‘macValue’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT32 macAddr = 0, macValue = 0;
                      ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2036:9: warning: unused variable ‘macAddr’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT32 macAddr = 0, macValue = 0;
         ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSIRQRelease’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2172:21: warning: unused variable ‘net_dev’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct net_device *net_dev = (struct net_device *)pNetDev;
                     ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsFreeSpinLock’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:4266:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  pLock = (OS_NDIS_MINIPORT_TIMER *) (pLockOrg->pContent);
        ^
In file included from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_os.h:48:0,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/rtmp_comm.h:62,
                 from /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:34:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktTailAdjust’:
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:893:36: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                    ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:917:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt, GET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt), (-_removedTagLen)); \
  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:5200:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST’
  OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST(pNetPkt, removedTagLen);
  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:893:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/include/os/rt_linux.h:917:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt, GET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(_pkt), (-_removedTagLen)); \
  ^
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:5200:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST’
  OS_PKT_TAIL_ADJUST(pNetPkt, removedTagLen);
  ^
  LD [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/mt7650u_sta_util.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/mt7650u_sta_util.mod.o
  LD [M]  /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL/os/linux/mt7650u_sta_util.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-66-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/UTIL'
/bin/sh cp_util.sh

make -C MODULE/ build_tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE'
make -C tools
make[2]: Entering directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE/tools'
/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE/tools/bin2h
make[1]: execvp: /media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE/tools/bin2h: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [build_tools] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/steve/3698-C654/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/Archer_T2U_V1_150901/MODULE'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Is that a USB wireless dongle?

Comment: Yeah, it's a USB wireless dongle, I have tried following steps here 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/577941/installing-the-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn727n-on-ubuntu-14-04
and I keep getting "make: *** [install] Error 2"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; uname -r; dkms status` terminal command.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: it's ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you also post the error message when you build the driver?

Comment: Run only `make` and post the result. The module does not build.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that driver does not build for the kernel 3.13.0-66-generic.

It is theoretically possible to adapt the code to that kernel, but IMHO it is not worth the effort.

Your device is fully supported by kernel 4.2. You can fix it this way:

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. It should work there.

You can wait a week or two when 4.2 is in official repositories for Ubuntu 14.04. Then you will be able yo install it by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

or install it now from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Do not forget to reboot after you install a new kernel.

I suggest checking that the 4.2 kernel is uploaded to main repos and removing the PPA in a while.

Comment: Just given this a go and still doesn't seem to build

Comment: What "this" you've given a go? With 4.2 kernel you do not need to build anything.

Comment: I meant I've installed the 4.2 kernel with the commands then tried to make the driver again

Comment: You do not need to make the driver for kernel 4.2.

Comment: just tried a second reinstall and it's all working. Thank you so much

Comment: It is working without the driver. It is just working.